# Asking for userinput unless they write no, then print all inputs as csv - Python

Tags: python, while-loop, stdout, user-input, stdin

I am looking for some way to keep asking user for an input string, and once they are done, I want to print all the responses back in console. Something like below.

```
while True:

    cityName = input("Write the name of the city visited and hit enter, 
    if you have another city write it after, once you are done, enter 
    no. ") 

    #Forexample user wrote, NY [hit enter], Los Angeles [hit enter], 
    #London [hit enter] No. 

    if cityName == 'no':
        break

    counter += 1 //Not sure about this part. 
    print(cityName.counter + ",") #Not sure about this part
    #I want it to print NY, Los Angeles, London.
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a list of city names. Then print the concatenated value for the list items.

```
city_names = []

while True:
    city_name = input(
        'Write the name of the city visited and hit enter, ' 
        'if you have another city write it after, once you '
        'are done, enter no. ') 
    if city_name == 'no': 
        break
    city_names.append(city_name)

print(', '.join(city_names))
```